# special laptop with DOS, XP and 7: SSD or HDD?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, laptop, ms-dos

I am setting up a laptop with special OS and Software.
OS will be DOS, Windows XP, Windows 7, drivers are available for XP.

Can I use a SSD?

Is it safe using a SSD? Would DOS/XP destroy the SSD if used for a longer time? (wear leveling?) Or does it not matter because the OS basically does not see the SSD but only a storage device and wear leveling (or else) is done by the onboard SSD controller?

Comment: Yes, the OS sees the SSD as a storage device and wear leveling is done internally by the SSD controller.  So that part isn't the issue, but the interface could be.  I don't think any SSDs have an IDE interface, which is what was around in the XP and early 7 days.  MS-DOS was 16 bit, if I remember right.  I suspect that if you are going to have an issue, it will be with finding drivers for the old OSes.

Comment: Ayup. Drivers for DOS (not virtualised) are going to be 'interesting' (tm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Or does it not matter because....
```

Both.

The onboard controllers of on SSD are quite smart these days. If you do not use a 10 year old SSD then destroying the SSD is not a relevant fear.

That does not means that you cannot run into performance degradation if you write **a lot** each days.  But for regular use any modern SSD should be fine.

But if you only do regular use and not write 1SSD size worth of of data each day then choose any SATA/SAS SSD or any NVMe SSD (but providing drivers in case of NVMe and old operating systems can be *interesting*).